# Django's get_current_language() returns None

Tags: python, django

When I use `django.utils.translations.get_current_language()`, it returns None. What am I missing?

My Django app has the following settings:

```
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en-us', _('English')),
    ('zh-cn', _('Chinese (Simplified)'))
)
```

I also have `LocaleMiddleware` in my `MIDDELWARE` settings.

Using Django 1.11

Comment: Is LocaleMiddleware mentioned at the right location i.e. after session and before common?

Comment: are you using `i18n_patterns` in urls.py of root?

Comment: where are you using `get_current_language`, is this in a view? Can you give a small reproducible example?